# array store a different number than input

Tags: javascript

I just stated learning JS and I was trying a very simple code when I got a strange result which I cannot explain why it happened. 
I tried to define a very simple array like below:

```
var a=['hello',0,"2313dog!"," ",45.78,-021,-657]
```

But once it’s executed in Chrome console the element -021 was changed to -17 , like:

```
["hello", 0, "2313dog!", " ", 45.78, -17, -657]
```

I know -021 is not a number, and I can add it as a tring, but I don't now why and how it changed to -17.
Can someone please explain what happened and if there is a name for this.
Thanks!

Comment: A number prefixed by a '0' is interpreted as an octal (base-8) number in javascript and other languages. So 2 * 8 + 1 = 17

Comment: @Mark You should post as an answer

Comment: Hey thanks man! Sometimes I see people getting flack for posting trivial answers, but if you say so...

Answer (score 3):

A number prefixed by a `0` is interpreted as an octal (base-8) number in javascript and other languages. So `2 * 8 + 1 = 17`.

Similarly, a number prefixed by `0x` is interpreted as hexadecimal (base-16), so `0x11` would also be converted to `17`.